# Flow CONTAINS on Case Subject not matching

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, contains

I have a before trigger flow that runs on CREATE that has a decision node to check if the case subject contains the phrase "intake session canceled".

I am using a case formula that trims and sets the case subject to lower case. Below is the decision node:

```
{!formula_SubjectLower} (intake session canceled for Matt d. on may 2, 2023 @ 2:00pm edt) Contains intake session canceled
```

Here is the decision node:

[image]

What is very interesting is that if I set contains to only "intake session", it works perfectly.

Here is the formula I am using for **"formula_SubjectLower"**

```
TRIM( LOWER( {!$Record.Subject} ))
```

My hunch is that:

- There are limits to how many words you can use in contains
- Subject may be a protected field in Salesforce

Comment: subject is definitely not a protected field though if encypted, CONTAINS won't work at all. I'd check to make sure you don't have any hidden non-printable whitespace characters in the comparand

Comment: Tried to reproduce and couldn't - flow decision entered as expected with the same subject as you pasted. Is there anything going on "extra" that might be relevant? Is that subject calculated in automation? My "reproduction" was pretty simple - one single before flow that set Description field if subject formula contained `intake session canceled`.

Comment: Is there a way to remove any unwanted chars?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I am going to take this up with Salesforce. It seems to be a bug.